# On which day goddess Sita was born?

Tags: ramayana, avatars, sita, birth

Although, goddess Sita's birth as per most scriptures, specifically the original Valmiki Ramayan is said to be non-uterine (ayonija), still the day of her being discovered by king Janaka maybe considered as her birth-date (tithi).

This is how the Valmiki Ramayan describes it -

> #### [Janaka describes](https://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/baala/sarga66/bala_66_frame.htm) Sita's birth as non-uterine.
>
> भूतलादुत्थिता सा तु व्यवर्धत ममात्मजा ।  वीर्यशुल्केति मे कन्या
> स्थापितेयमयोनिजा ॥ १-६६-१४ ॥
>
> > 14. Hers is a non-uterine birth as she surfaced from the surface of the
> >     earth, but fostered as my own soul-born girl and I determined [to give
> >     her in marriage to a bridegroom where his] boldness is the only
> >     bounty, I receive in that marriage.
>
> ---
>
> #### [Sita narrates to Devi Anusuya](https://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/ayodhya/sarga118/ayodhya_118_frame.htm)
>
> तस्य लान्गल हस्तस्य कर्षतः क्षेत्र मण्डलम् । अहम् किल उत्थिता भित्त्वा
> जगतीम् नृपतेः सुता ॥ २-११८-२८ ॥
>
> > 28. "While he was furrowing a territory of land, holding a plough in his
> >     hand, it is so said that I came forth, splitting up the land, as a
> >     daughter of that king."
>
> ....
>
> अन्तरिक्षे च वाग् उक्ता अप्रतिमा मानुषी किल । एवम् एतन् नर पते धर्मेण
> तनया तव ॥ २-११८-३१ ॥
>
> > 31. "It is said that voice resembling that of a human being in the air
> >     above me rang out, saying": "O, King! Let it be so. This divine child
> >     without a match is a daughter to you, rightly."

However, nowhere, I can locate a date (tithi) on which Sita was "born" or "discovered" by Janaka, unlike Sri Rama for whom Sri Valmiki gives an exact tithi in [V.R. 1.18.8,8,10,11](https://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/baala/sarga18/bala_18_frame.htm), popularly known as Rama-Navami ( celebrated on Chaitra Shukla Paksha Ninth).

Interestingly several articles give a date of birth (tithi) for Sita too, as Vaishakha Shukla Paksha Navami as Sita Jayanti or Sita Navami.

This is what the famous vedic jyotish website [Drikpanchanga writes](https://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/sita-navami/sita-navami-date-time.html) -

> **Sita Navami is celebrated as birth anniversary of Goddess Sita. This
> day is also known as Sita Jayanti**. Married women keep fast on Sita
> Navami day and pray to seek long lives of their husbands.
>
> **Sita Jayanti is celebrated on Navami Tithi during Shukla Paksha of
> Vaishakha month. It is believed that Goddess Sita was born on Tuesday
> in Pushya Nakshatra.** Goddess Sita was married to Lord Rama who was
> also born on Navami Tithi during Shukla Paksha of Chaitra month. On
> Hindu calendar Sita Jayanti falls after one month of Rama Navami.

---

### Question -

Are there any scriptural references for goddess Sita's birth tithi, Sita Jayanti?

What scriptures (or sects) describe or believe the birth or discovery of goddess Sita on the month of Vaishakha in the Shukla Paksha on the Navami tithi?

Comment: Interestingly the tithi of this year's Sita Jayanti, as per the drikpanchanga is today on the day of writing this question (May 10, 2022)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my research, I couldn't find any specific scriptural reference to goddess Sita's birth tithi to fall on *Vaishakha in the Shukla Paksha on the Navami tithi*.

However, as suggested by a prolific user (*thank You!*), one sect of the **Ramanandi Sampradaya Vaishnavas** does believe this tithi to be the birth date of the goddess Sita.

In their "[official website](https://lordrama.co.in/sri-vaishnav-parampara.html)" of the sorts, they have mentioned this.

> [image]
>
> Parampara (Śrī-Sampradāya unbroken Lineage)
>
> ०१) सर्वावातारी सर्वेश्वर साकेतबिहारी भगवान श्री राम (नित्य-बिहारी,
> एवं विभूति-लोक प्राकट्यः श्री रामनवमी, त्रेतायुग)
>
> > 1. Sarvāvātāri
> >    Sarvesvar Sākétabihari Bhagavān Sri Rama (Nitya-Bihari, and appearance
> >    day in Vibhūti-Löka : Sri Ramanavami, Trētāyuga)
>
> ०२) सर्वेश्वरी
> साकेतबिहरिणी श्री सीता (नित्य-बिहारिणी, एवं वैशाख शुक्ल नवमी,
> त्रेतायुग )
>
> > **02) Sarvēśvari Sākētabiharini Sri Sita (Nitya-Bihārini,
> > and appearance day in Vibhuti-Loka : Vaisakha Sukla Navami, Tretayuga)**
>
> ०३) श्री हनुमान (कार्तिक कृष्ण चतुर्दशी)
>
> > 3. Sri Hanumana (Kartika
> >    Krsna Caturdasi)
>
> ०४) श्री ब्रह्मा (अक्षय नवमी, सतयुग)
>
> > 4. Sri Brahma
> >    (Aksaya Navami, Satayuga)

**So, at least as per this documentation provided by the Ramanandi Sampradaya, in the descendant students of which Shri Gosvami Tulsidasji belonged too, the birth-tithi of goddess Sita is - *Vaishakha in the Shukla Paksha on the Navami tithi.***

Comment: 14th century Maithili paṇḍita Rudradhara Upadhyāya wrote in his compendium Varṣakṛtya about celebrating Vaiśākha śuklā navamī as Sītā's birthday & Mārgaśīrṣa śuklā pañcamī as the day of her marriage. Being situated close to Mithilā, Sītānavamī is also celebrated in Bengal too.